# I can't switch to another activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

When I try to switch to this activity(User_Profile_Page).I'm getting this error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"
> Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView"

User_Profile_Page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textDirection="locale"
    tools:context=".pages.User_Profile_Page"

    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile_button2"
            android:layout_width="131dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:text="Something"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.026"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.775" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/unichatLabelMainPage2"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
            android:text="UNICHAT"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#F19B1A"
            android:textSize="42sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="117dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.026"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.327"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_followers_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="11"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.673"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folllowers_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_follow_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="123"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.928"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/follow_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_post_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.449"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/post_textView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/folllowers_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Followers"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.704"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.218" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Posts"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.439"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.218" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/follow_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="29dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="Follow"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.952"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.218" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_profile_button"
            android:layout_width="131dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:text="Edit Your Profile"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.541"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.78" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share_profile_button"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:text="Share"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.775" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_liked_underline"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Posts_Button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:onClick="posts_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Posts"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.208"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/liked_Button"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:onClick="liked_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="Liked"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.776"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/user_graph" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

User_Profile_Page.kt

```
package com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.pages

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.R
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.databinding.ActivityUserProfilePageBinding
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.fragments.LikedPostFragment
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.fragments.PostListFragment

class User_Profile_Page : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityUserProfilePageBinding
    private var fragmentStatus : Int =0
    var user_mail =""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding=ActivityUserProfilePageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view=binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        user_mail=intent.getStringExtra("user_mail").toString()
    }
    fun posts_button(view: View){
        if(fragmentStatus!=0){
            val fragment=PostListFragment(user_mail)
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView,fragment)
                .commit()

            fragmentStatus=0
            }
    }

    fun liked_button(view: View){
        if(fragmentStatus!=1){
            val fragment=LikedPostFragment(user_mail)
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView,fragment)
                .commit()

            fragmentStatus=1
        }
    }

}
```

And my fragment code :

```
package com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.fragments

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.R
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.adapter.RecyclerAdapter
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.databinding.FragmentPostListBinding
import com.gokhanakbas.unichatdeneme.object_class.Posts
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class PostListFragment(var user_mail : String) : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    val postList = ArrayList<Posts>()
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPostListBinding
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerAdapter


    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        auth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        getPostSelf()
        recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerAdapter(postList)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter



    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //binding = FragmentPostListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding = FragmentPostListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun getPostSelf() {
        //Buraya Firestore dan kullanıcıya ait postları çekeceğiz.

        firestore.collection("Posts").whereEqualTo("post_mail", user_mail)
            .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->

                if (exception != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext, exception.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {

                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        if (!snapshot.isEmpty) {

                            var documents = snapshot.documents
                            postList.clear()
                            for (document in documents) {
                                var postObject = Posts(user_mail)
                                postObject.postLabel = document.get("post_label") as String
                                postObject.postDesc = document.get("post_desc") as String
                                postObject.postTime = document.get("post_time") as String
                                postObject.postFullName = document.get("post_FullName") as String
                                postList.add(postObject)
                            }
                            recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }


                    }

                }
            }
    }
    }
```

[image: User_Profile_Page.xml]

I tried to change navhost actions.But it's not working